# Google ads don't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adsense

I integrated adsense with my site and I tried auto-ads and it works.
but I want to use Ad-units to have better controll over ads positions and so on.

Unfortunately when I use ad-units `data-ad-status="unfilled"` always unfilled.
So ads dont show at all.

Sample link: https://hichee.com/listings/11665?check_in=2022-10-18&check_out=2022-10-25

you can see that `ins` elements exist but they are unfilled..
Any suggestion?

Comment: You've got multiple CORS errors that I can see.  I'd start with that.  Use the developer tools in the browsers to help you debug this.

Comment: Sorry how can I handle that?
Also If cors is the case,  Why auto-ads did work and ad-units didn't work?

Comment: @stdunbar ^^^^^

Comment: @stdunbar probably you have adblocker. Can u confirm that using incognito window?

Comment: I see only single `<ins>` element and that one is created by the auto ads logic. I don't see any `<ins>` elements that you added yourself.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau 
I run document.getElementByTagName("ins") and I was able to find 3 ins elements .
Also how do you know if this ins is coming from auto ads or ad unit?

Comment: We are interested only in top-level <ins> elements that have class adsbygoogle. Like `document.querySelectorAll('ins.adsbygoogle')`. If you create ad unit yourself (by creating it first on google.com/adsense) there you should get a snippet with `<ins>` element. That snippet should contain attributes like `data-ad-client` and probably `data-ad-slot`. There is no such elements on your site so I don't think you actually added manually ad units to your page.

Comment: Good catch, It now works (was env var issue) . but if you checked again the diminsions is 0x0 , can you tell why does that happen? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau ping , please :)

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau please help :(

Comment: Dimension 0x0 of one <ins> element is fine. It's used to send "invisible" ad request to fetch some auto ads. I see you added an ins `data-ad-slot=3496663743`. It has 2 issues: 
1. It should have `adsbygoogle` class.
2. You need to call `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` to initialize it.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau Thanks, It worked. Do you know how can I render a wrapper around the ad and remove it when status is unfilled? because I can't access the parent (wrapper) with css since :has isn't available yet.